# Split date column into YYYY.MM.DD

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column in the format of 20180531.
I need to split this properly i.e. I can get 2018/05/31.
This is a dataframe column that I have and I need to deal with it in a datetime format.

Currently this column is identified as int64 type

Comment: Currently this column is identified as int64 type

Comment: Might want to [edit] that comment into your question - comments aren't guaranteed to stay around for long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient it'll be but if you convert it to a string, and the use `pd.to_datetime` with a `.format=`..., eg:

```
df['actual_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['your_column'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
```

As [Emma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956135/emma) points out - the `astype(str)` is redundant here and just:

```
df['actual_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['your_column'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

will work fine.

Comment: I don't think you need `astype(str)`.  it can take int type.

Comment: @Emma wow... so it does... I didn't know that... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integer dates would always be fixed width at 8 digits, you may try:

```py
df['dt'] = df['dt_int'].astype(str).str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\1-\2-\3')
```